# Electron debugger detaches as soon as it is attached

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, electron

I am trying to use the [Debugger](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/debugger/) object of Electron main process to enable the 
[Chrome DevTools Profiler](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Profiler/). I have almost copied the demo code under the Debugger documentation page (linked above) where the first step is to call the attach() function to attach the Debugger to webContents. However, as soon as the attach happens, the debugger gets detached. I know this because of the on-detach callback that I have setup. I don't know if I am missing something like enabling a port or setting a flag somewhere. Any and all help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
var currentWindow = require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow();
try {
    currentWindow.webContents.debugger.attach('1.1');

    // Sending messages back to server for logging
    wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {msg: "about to enable debugger!"});

    var attachMessage;
    if (currentWindow.webContents.debugger.isAttached() === true) {
        attachMessage = "Debugger is attached!";
    } else {
        attachMessage = "Debugger is not attached!";
    }

    wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {msg: attachMessage});

    currentWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Debugger.enable', function () {

        wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {msg: "in debug enable"});
        currentWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand("Profiler.enable", null, function(error, result) {
            if (error !== null) {
                wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {error: error, result: result});
            } else {
                wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {msg: 'Profiling enabled!'});
            }
        });
    });
    wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {msg: "about to exit try block!"});
} catch (err) {
    wsio.emit('browserProfileInfo', {msg: 'Debugger attach failed : ', err:err});
}

currentWindow.webContents.debugger.on('detach', (event, reason) => {
    wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {msg: 'Debugger detached due to :' + event + reason});
});

currentWindow.webContents.debugger.on('message', (event, method, params) => {
    wsio.emit('proxyConsole', {msg: {method: method, params: params}});
});
```

Comment: Please provide code example.

Comment: Sorry! Edited to include code.